# Do Pokemon forget a move when changing form?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-seventh-generation

When browsing Bulbapedia, I have noticed that some Pokemon with alternate forms have different move learnsets depending on their form.

One such example is Hoopa. Hoopa Confined learns Phantom Force at level 35; Hoopa Unbound does not learn anything at that level. At level 46, Hoopa Confined learns Zen Headbutt, but Hoopa Unbound learns Knock Off. Then at level 55 Hoopa Confined learns Shadow Ball, while Hoopa Unbound learns Dark Pulse. Finally, only Hoopa Confined learns Nasty Plot at level 68.

Another example is Deoxys. I assume there are also others.

What happens when Pokemon that knows move exclusive to one form changes form? In example above, if my Hoopa Confined knows Phantom Force and Zen Headbutt, can it still use it when it changes form to Hoopa Unbound?
Is the answer the same for all Pokemon with different learnsets for different forms, or are there exceptions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Except for Rotom and Kyurem, all Pokémon keep their moves when changing form. The form-exclusive moves are the following:

- Fan Rotom's Air Slash
- Frost Rotom's Blizzard
- Heat Rotom's Overheat
- Mow Rotom's Leaf Storm
- Wash Rotom's Hydro Pump
- Kyurem's Glaciate and Scary Face
- White Kyurem's Fusion Flare and Ice Burn
- Black Kyurem's Fusion Bolt and Freeze Shock

Confined Hoopa can know Hyperspace Hole, but it will not be able to use it in battle.

Comment: For an idea of how all other Pokémon work look up the Lotad line. Ludicolo learns no moves at level up (a few at level 1, but that's a mechanical trick to make sure wild Ludicolo have moves). So you want to plan ahead as to when you evolve your Lombre. In some lines you can get a better mon by postponing evolution, which is why these differences exist. Form changes are an extention of that, switch forms several times for your perfect build.

Comment: @Monster This question is not asking about evolution.